# Private compile-time -> run-time adapter. Strange compilation error

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Basically, this code fails with a very strange error:

```
<source>:75:29: error: cannot convert 'get_view<main()::<unnamed struct>, run_time::data_view>::operator()(const main()::<unnamed struct>&) const::View::code' from type 'int (get_view<main()::<unnamed struct>, run_time::data_view>::operator()(const main()::<unnamed struct>&) const::View::)() const' to type 'int'
   75 |                 return data.code;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T3h1a7zne

```
template <typename SourceT, typename ViewT>
struct get_view;

template <typename SourceT>
struct get_view<SourceT, SourceT>
{
    constexpr decltype(auto) operator()(const SourceT &source) const
    {
        return source;
    }
};

// api.h 

#include <iostream>

class compile_time
{
public:

  template <typename DataT>
  void operator()(const DataT &data) const
  {
      std::cout << "compile-time: " << data.code << std::endl;
  }
};

class run_time
{
    // How to make data_view private?
// private:
public:
    class data_view; 

public:

  template <typename DataT>
  void operator()(const DataT &data) const
  {
      (*this)(get_view<DataT, data_view>{}(data));
  }

private:
  void operator()(const data_view &data) const;
};

class run_time::data_view
{
public:

  virtual int code() const = 0;

protected:
  ~data_view() = default; // do not own this 
};


template <typename DataT>
struct get_view<DataT, run_time::data_view>
{
    // don't want to return std::unique_ptr<data_view>
    auto operator()(const DataT &data) const
    {
        struct View : run_time::data_view {
            const DataT& data;

            View(const DataT &data)
              : data(data)
            {}
            
            int code() const override
            {
                return data.code;
            }
        };

        return View(data);
    }
};


// .cpp

void run_time::operator()(const run_time::data_view &dataView) const
{
    std::cout << "run-time: " << dataView.code() << std::endl;
} 

// main.cpp

int main()
{
    struct {
        double irrelevant;
        int code;
    } data{42, 815};

    compile_time{}(data);
    run_time{}(data); // does not compile!!!

    return 0;
}
```

I can't find an explanation for it.
Why does it say that `data.code` is of a function type?

Is it possible to make this work? I don't want `data_view` to be returned as `std::unique_ptr`.

What I expect:

- Upon `get_view` partial specialization for `run_time::data_view` `data_view` is a complete type.
- `operator()(const DataT &)` is specialized after `main::<unnamed struct>` (which is `data`) has been created, so it is also a complete type.
- `auto` can be deduced: both `data_view` and `DataT` are complete
- `const run_time::data_view &` is a public base of the returned local struct, so the object's reference is implicitly convertible

So can anyone explain the reason why it fails and how to make it work without resorting to heap allocations? (`run_time::data_view` should be private. I don't want it to be used anywhere outside the class or designated adapter `get_view`).

---

This worked:

```
  template <typename DataT>
  void operator()(const DataT &data) const
  {
      const data_view &view = get_view<DataT, data_view>{}(data);
      (*this)(view);
  }
```

I guess it causes a recursion because `auto` deduced from `get_view` is not of a type `const data_view&`. So the compiler gets confused on which `operator()(data)` to invoke. With explicit conversion to a reference it gets clear.

**However, there is a question of why it decides to go with a template first, but not with an overload that takes a const reference.**

Comment: That's one hell of an ugly sucker. Looks like it's trying to use the function `code` in place of the variable `code`. No clue why yet.

Comment: @user4581301 I updated the question (with a solution). It boils down to the order of signature resolutions.

Comment: I don't really see why you are surprised. `get_view::operator()` returns a `View` which is inherited from `data_view`, but not the same type. So binding the argument to a reference of exactly matching type in the template overload is a better fit than binding to a base class reference in the non-template one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an ambiguity during function resolutions:
`get_view` returns a `deduced` type by value that is a good candidate for
`template <typename DataT> operator()(const DataT &)`, thus ignoring the existing overload `operator()(const data_view &)`.

Providing an explicit cast before operator's invocation solves the problem.

```
  template <typename DataT>
  void operator()(const DataT &data) const
  {
      const data_view &view = get_view<DataT, data_view>{}(data);
      (*this)(view);
  }
```